# Will using two different tracking codes affect my SERP

Tags: seo, google-analytics, web-hosting, tracking, search-results

Hello everyone and thanks for your time!

I am now facing a problem after a site migration.

New site is basically an improved version of old site, with the same content and some extras. After pointing the domain name to the new site, the old site was still online for a while but didn't get any traffic. The new site has its own tracking code.

So, old tracking code has age (something like 7 years) but no visitors for a month, but new tracking code is a month old with an acceptable traffic.

How to you think google will react if I add old tracking code to new site?

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Google Tracking Code has nothing to do with rank, SEO, or anything else except tracking usage. Do not move the tracking code from your old site to the new site. It will cause you problems with double reporting and confusion. It might make Google mad too. Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

As Closetnoc mentioned it wont affect your SERPS, but you can actually run two analytics tracking codes together, as outlined here: [Multiple tracking codes on web pages](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) and here [Working with Multiple Tracking Objects](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers)

However I dont see any point in having two tracking codes. As the new code only has 1 months worth of traffic, I would simply remove it and re add the old tracking code. You don't want to lose all those 7 years of data.